Android [ksp] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap$Builder.buildOrThrow()'
I update libs to latest version and include jvm to 17 but until now the problem i have its said that [ksp] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap$Builder.buildOrThrow()' 
i already look at the website and said maybe its use old version guava, so i try to implementation("com.google.guava:guava:33.3.1-android") in my gradle and still not work
i cant find which libs that use guava, try to updated the libs to the latest version and guava also but still same problem, i give you gradle.kts
app Gradle kts
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.konan.properties.Properties

plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("io.realm.kotlin")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
    id("kotlin-parcelize")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
    id("com.google.firebase.crashlytics")
}

val props = Properties()
file("../local.properties").inputStream().use { props.load(it) }

android {
    namespace = "com.honcho.quickfire"
    compileSdk = 34

    signingConfigs {
        getByName("debug") {
            keyAlias = props.getProperty("debug.key.alias")
            keyPassword = props.getProperty("debug.key.password")
            storeFile = file(props.getProperty("debug.key.path"))
            storePassword = props.getProperty("debug.key.password.store")
        }
        create("release") {
            keyAlias = props.getProperty("release.key.alias")
            keyPassword = props.getProperty("release.key.password")
            storeFile = file(props.getProperty("release.key.path"))
            storePassword = props.getProperty("release.key.password.store")
        }
        create("beta") {
            keyAlias = props.getProperty("release.key.alias")
            keyPassword = props.getProperty("release.key.password")
            storeFile = file(props.getProperty("release.key.path"))
            storePassword = props.getProperty("release.key.password.store")
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.honcho.quickfire"
        minSdk = 23
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 81
        versionName = "2.0.24"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
            buildConfigField("String", "HOST", props.getProperty("RELEASE_HOST_API"))
            buildConfigField("String", "GALLERY_HOST", props.getProperty("RELEASE_GALLERY_HOST"))
            buildConfigField("String", "WEB_HOST", props.getProperty("RELEASE_WEB_HOST"))
            buildConfigField("String", "SOCKET_HOST", props.getProperty("RELEASE_SOCKET_HOST"))
            buildConfigField("String", "MIXPANEL_TOKEN", props.getProperty("MIXPANEL_TOKEN"))
            buildConfigField("String", "DATADOG_TOKEN", props.getProperty("DATADOG_TOKEN"))
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("release")
        }

        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix = ".debug"
            isDebuggable = true
            buildConfigField("String", "HOST", props.getProperty("DEBUG_HOST_API"))
            buildConfigField("String", "GALLERY_HOST", props.getProperty("DEBUG_GALLERY_HOST"))
            buildConfigField("String", "WEB_HOST", props.getProperty("DEBUG_WEB_HOST"))
            buildConfigField("String", "SOCKET_HOST", props.getProperty("DEBUG_SOCKET_HOST"))
            buildConfigField("String", "MIXPANEL_TOKEN", props.getProperty("MIXPANEL_TOKEN"))
            buildConfigField("String", "DATADOG_TOKEN", props.getProperty("DATADOG_TOKEN"))
        }

        create("beta") {
            applicationIdSuffix = ".beta"
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
            buildConfigField("String", "HOST", props.getProperty("RELEASE_HOST_API"))
            buildConfigField("String", "GALLERY_HOST", props.getProperty("RELEASE_GALLERY_HOST"))
            buildConfigField("String", "WEB_HOST", props.getProperty("RELEASE_WEB_HOST"))
            buildConfigField("String", "SOCKET_HOST", props.getProperty("RELEASE_SOCKET_HOST"))
            buildConfigField("String", "MIXPANEL_TOKEN", props.getProperty("MIXPANEL_TOKEN"))
            buildConfigField("String", "DATADOG_TOKEN", props.getProperty("DATADOG_TOKEN"))
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        isCoreLibraryDesugaringEnabled = true
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
        buildConfig = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        // kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        tasks.withType<JavaCompile> {
            options.compilerArgs.addAll(arrayOf("-parameters", "-Xlint:deprecation"))
        }
    }
}

kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(17)
}

ksp {
    arg("jvmTarget", "17")
}

dependencies {
    coreLibraryDesugaring("com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5")
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.13.1")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.9.2")

    implementation(project(mapOf("path" to ":service")))
    implementation(files("libs/pronto-release.aar"))

    // Kotlin
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.9.0")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.9.0")

    // Compose
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.09.03"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")

    // Lifecycle
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.8.6")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.8.6")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.8.6")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.8.6")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose:2.8.6")

    // Navigation 6.0
    implementation ("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.8.2")

    // Work manager
    implementation("androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.9.1")
    implementation("androidx.work:work-multiprocess:2.9.1")

    // CameraX
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-core:1.3.4")
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.3.4")
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.3.4")
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-video:1.3.4")
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-view:1.3.4")
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.3.4")

    // Test
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.09.03"))
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.2.1")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.6.1")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")

    // Hilt
    implementation ("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.52")
    ksp("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.52")

    implementation ("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.2.0")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-work:1.2.0")
    ksp("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.2.0")

    // Firebase
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.0"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth")

    // FirebaseUI for Firebase Auth
    implementation("com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:8.0.2")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.6.0")

    // Ktor
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:2.3.4")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:2.3.4")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-json:2.3.4")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:2.3.4")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:2.3.4")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:2.3.4")

    // Coil
    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.6.0")
    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil:2.6.0")

    // Guava
    implementation("com.google.guava:guava:33.3.1-android")

    // Splash Screen
    implementation ("androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.1")
    implementation("androidx.compose.animation:animation-graphics:1.7.3")

    // Realm MongoDB
    implementation ("io.realm.kotlin:library-base:1.10.0")
    implementation ("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.9.0")

    // Event Bus
    implementation("org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.3.1")
    // ExifInterface
    implementation("androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.3.7")
    // Datastore
    implementation("androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.1.1")
    // QrCode
    implementation("com.github.androidmads:QRGenerator:1.0.1")
    // GSON
    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.11.0")
    // ZoomImage
    implementation ("net.engawapg.lib:zoomable:1.5.2")
    // MixPanel
    implementation("com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:7.4.0")
    //Tooltip Balloon
    implementation("com.github.skydoves:balloon-compose:1.6.4")
    // Datadog
    implementation("com.datadoghq:dd-sdk-android-logs:2.6.2")
}

service Gradle kts i use this project to handle services to backend
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("io.realm.kotlin")
    id("kotlinx-serialization")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.honcho.service"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 23
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles("consumer-rules.pro")
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }

        create("beta") {}
    }
    compileOptions {
        isCoreLibraryDesugaringEnabled = true
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = 17.toString()
        tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptGenerateStubsTask>().configureEach {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = 17.toString()
            }
        }
    }
}

kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(17)
}

ksp {
    arg("jvmTarget", "17")
}

dependencies {

    coreLibraryDesugaring("com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.1.2")
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.13.1")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0")

    // Kotlin
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.9.0")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.9.0")

    // SDK Camera
    compileOnly(files("libs/pronto-release.aar"))

    // implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0")

    // Guava
    implementation("com.google.guava:guava:33.3.1-android")

    // Hilt
    implementation ("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.52")
    ksp("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.52")

    // Realm
    implementation("io.realm.kotlin:library-base:3.0.0")

    // Ktor
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:3.0.0")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-okhttp:3.0.0")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-auth:3.0.0")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:3.0.0")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:3.0.0")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:3.0.0")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-gson:3.0.0")

    // Firebase
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.0"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx")

    // FirebaseUI for Firebase Auth
    implementation("com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:8.0.2")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.6.0")

    // Test
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.2.1")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.6.1")

    // Serialization
    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.11.0")
    // Centrifuge
    implementation("io.github.centrifugal:centrifuge-java:0.4.2")
}

This root Gradle
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.kotlinExtension

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.7.0" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.25" apply false
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.25-1.0.20" apply false
    id("org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention") version("0.5.0") apply false
    id("io.realm.kotlin") version "1.10.0" apply false
    id("com.android.library") version "8.7.0" apply false
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.52" apply false
    id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.1" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization") version "1.8.10" apply false
    id("com.google.firebase.crashlytics") version "2.9.9" apply false
}

subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {
        kotlinExtension.jvmToolchain(17)
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force("com.google.guava:guava:33.3.1-android")
    }
}


Hi, Any luck with this issue? We’re facing the same problem while creating the release bundle. We’ve tried all the suggestions from GPT and Google, but nothing seems to work.

We faced the same issue. Could solve it with following versions of kotlin, ksp and realm:
[versions]
kotlin = "2.0.21"
ksp = "2.0.21-1.0.28"
realm = "3.0.0"


Forcing Guava to a very specific version 33.2.0 worked with my case:
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.google.guava:guava:33.2.0-android'
    }
}

